# How to filter columns in one table based on the same columns in another table using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to filter columns in one table (fixTablehb004_p) based on the same columns in another table (filtredTable109_p)

I first wanted to use this code:

```
 val filtredTablehb004_p = fixTablehb004_p
    .where($"servizio_rap" === filtredTable109_p.col("servizio_rap"))
    .where($"filiale_rap" === filtredTable109_p.col("filiale_rap"))
    .where($"codice_rap" === filtredTable109_p.col("codice_rap"))
```

But it gave out an error.

Then I tried the code based on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690847/filter-data-in-one-table-based-on-data-in-another-table), and I get this code. But the problem is that there are extra columns, I know what you can do `drop(columnName)`, but I want to ask you if I'm doing it right and if there is another better option

```
  val filtredTablehb004_p = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM fixTablehb004_p " +
    "JOIN filtredTable109_p " +
    "ON fixTablehb004_p.servizio_rap = filtredTable109_p.servizio_rap AND " +
    "fixTablehb004_p.filiale_rap  = filtredTable109_p.filiale_rap AND " +
    "fixTablehb004_p.codice_rap = filtredTable109_p.codice_rap ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take 2 sample dataframes and see how we can select required columns or avoid duplicate key column names in joined output dataframe.

**USING DATAFRAME API:**

```
val df1 = Seq(("A1", "A2", 1), ("A3", "A4", 2), ("A1", "A3", 3))
    .toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

val df2 = Seq(("A1", "A2", 10), ("A3", "A4", 11))
    .toDF("c1", "c2", "c4")

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tab1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tab2")
```

If column names which you used for joining condition from both dataframes are same then output dataframe will have duplicate columns. To avoid this you can pass all those columns as `Seq` to `join()`.

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("c1", "c2")).show()

+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
| A1| A2|  1| 10|
| A3| A4|  2| 11|
+---+---+---+---+
```

To select required columns from specific dataframe you can use below syntax:

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("c1", "c2")).select('c1, 'c2, df1("c3")).show()

// OR

df1.join(df2, df1("c1") === df2("c1") && df1("c2") === df2("c2"))
   .select(df1("c1"), df1("c2"), df1("c3")).show()
+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3|
+---+---+---+
| A1| A2|  1|
| A3| A4|  2|
+---+---+---+
```

**USING SQL API:**

```
spark.sql(
    """
      |SELECT t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c4 FROM tab1 t1
      |JOIN tab2 t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
      |""".stripMargin).show()
  
//OR

spark.sql(
    """
      |SELECT c1, c2, t2.c4 FROM tab1 t1
      |JOIN tab2 t2 USING(c1, c2)
      |""".stripMargin).show()

+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c4|
+---+---+---+
| A1| A2| 10|
| A3| A4| 11|
+---+---+---+
```